# UI-based Tool for Qualitative Evaluation of Data Quality

Tags: data, visualization, tools, data-quality

Dear DS StackExchange community,

I'm currently searching the interwebs for a (near-)ready-to-use solution, to perform a qualitative evaluation of extracted features from video data. In my head the tool looks something like the screenshot below (taken from the annotation tool [prodigy](https://prodi.gy/demo)), in the sense that a video is displayed at the top and underneath one would see a plot of a corresponding feature (selected e.g. via a drop-down menu) extracted from the video. This includes (nearly) every kind of data you could think of being extracted from a video, e.g. time-based data like a volume profile, things like extracted text transcripts etc etc... The user could then simply vote if the data matches qualitatively to what he sees/hears in the video by clicking the "accept", "reject" or "ignore" buttons as seen at the bottom of the screenshot:

[image: prodigy-screenshot]

Prodigy itself has a basic ["review and evaluation"](https://prodi.gy/docs/recipes#review) functionality, but for now only for text annotations in the context of NLP.

Of course one solution would be to develop something like this myself with plotly's Dash and some backend solution, but it would save me days if not weeks, if something like this already exists in some form, either as a open-source or even commercial solution.

Any kind of help / idea / hint is much appreciated!